# Reading the URL that triggered a fallback when offline

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

I have a web app that is running offline on a device with no network connection.

The HTML5 AppCache loads resources and page URLs that are needed, but when the user selects a page that has not been loaded, the fallback page is loaded.

What I need is a way for a JavaScript function on that fallback page to see the previous URL that triggered it.

I'm having difficulty finding a mechanism to do this would work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

`document.referrer`

Should give you the page last visited.